# What is the time complexity of if-else statement inside a while loop?

Tags: sql-server

I want to calculate the time complexity of if-else statement inside a while loop but I am not sure how.

Comment: What do you mean by the "time complexity"? If you will, how much slower it would be, slower than *what*? A set-based solution? Very likely it would be *vastly* slower as SQL is a set based language, and thus it excels at set based solutions. There are very few times you should be using loops in SQL.

Comment: Like big O notation.

Comment: Code:
int i = 0;
while(i<6)
{
      if(i%2==0)
         print("even number");
      else
         print("odd number");
      i = i + 1;
}

Comment: That isn't valid T-SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to measure the elapsed time in the BEGIN END block;

```
[![DECLARE @Counter INT 
DECLARE @TimeStart AS DATETIME
DECLARE @TimeStop AS DATETIME
SET @Counter=1
WHILE ( @Counter <= 10)
BEGIN
 PRINT 'The counter value is = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@Counter)
     IF @Counter %4 =0
     BEGIN
     SET @TimeStart=GETDATE()

     WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:001';  
     END
   SET @TimeStop =GETDATE()
   PRINT 'The elapsed time is = ' + CAST(DATEDIFF(MICROSECOND,@TimeStart,@TimeStop) AS VARCHAR(1000)) + ' microsecond'
   SET @TimeStart= NULL
   SET @TimeStop= NULL
   
    SET @Counter  = @Counter  + 1
END
```

[image: ScreenShot]